# How to check what version of a SilverStripe addon you're using?

Tags: ubuntu, silverstripe

How to check what version of a SilverStripe addon you're using? 
Lets say I have silverstripe/blog installed via composer and I want to check which version I have installed -- How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`composer show silverstripe/blog`

Example output:

```
name     : silverstripe/blog
descrip. : A fresh take on blogging in Silverstripe set out to tackle the issue of a cluttered Site Tree.
keywords : blog, news, silverstripe
versions : * 3.0.x-dev
type     : silverstripe-vendormodule
...
```

Or `composer show | grep silverstripe/blog`

```
silverstripe/blog  3.0.x-dev ae953b9  A fresh take on blogging in Silverstripe set out to tackle the iss...
```

Comment: I was trying to do this command in the wrong directory and kept wondering why it didn't show up. This worked, thanks dude